# With a dynamic mic is it possible to have as low noise as a condenser?

Tags: microphone, noise, hiss

*This is a question just out of curiosity*.
I have a Rode NT1-A microphone and also a Rode Podmic. I run both of them through a Yamaha MG12XU mixer.
The Podmic goes through an sE Electronics DM1 Dynamite before reaching the mixer.

Because of the DM1, the gain knob for both mics is almost at 12 o'clock on the mixer.
When I listen to the recordings from both mics in the same environment, I notice that the Podmic has a low hiss in the background, but the NT1-A is dead quite, to a level that sometimes I doubt that it is on.
I know that dynamic mics generally have a lower output signal, and need to drive the preamp more, and thus produce more noise (the hiss).

My question is:
Just out of curiosity, is it possible to achieve the same clean output I have from the NT1-A from any dynamic mic?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic mics don't really have any measurable SNR. The hiss you can hear is going to be from your gain stages, not the mic itself.

See https://service.shure.com/s/article/what-are-the-noise-specs-for-a-dynamic-mic-like-the-sm58?language=en_US

Comment: Is it possible to have a signal chain so clean that the hiss is eliminated?  
I should mention that the hiss is very low, and only noticeable if you listen very carefully. And most people will never notice the difference.

But is it physically possible  to eliminate that hiss? Or maybe because of the electronics components it is not?

Comment: My prime suspect would be the MG12, but I've never owned or even probably heard one.